# Retrieve the Most recent Date based on Time

Tags: sql, date, timestamp

EX :

```
  ID       Date(with time)          Price
  ----        -------                ------ 
   A          23-Aug-12 (09:25pm)      10(cosider this was the latest on this date)
   A          25-May-10                20
   A          23-Aug-12 (8:20pm)       30
   A          23-Aug-12 (7:00pm)       35
   B          03-Apr-09                45
   B          05-Dec-10                60
```

I want to Retrieve ID,Date,Price i.e If for two same dates if der are multiple prices then I have to select the date that is latest Update on date based on Timestamp included.

Expected output :

```
              A,23-Aug,12,10
              A,25-May-10,20
              B,03-Apr-09,45
              B,05-Dec-10,60
```

Answer (score 0):

Most versions of SQL support the `row_number` function.  Extracting the date from a datetime varies between databases.  Here is one way to do what you want:

```
select id, datetime, price
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, cast(datetime as date) order by datetime desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This gives the general structure.  The exact syntax varies by database.

Answer (score 0):

Try something this:-

```
SELECT
    ID,

    MAX(date)
FROM
    Some_Unnamed_Table
GROUP BY
    ID
ORDER BY
    ID
```